# VBA Loop through each row in multiple columns and paste a set of values in separate range if criteria met

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, copy-paste

I have a sheet with a large number of columns and only 27 rows. The data I'm looping through starts in column B3. I need to loop through each row with data starting in row 3 of each column. If a cell is NOT zero, then paste the value FROM COLUMN A in the same row and paste that value in the cells two below the last row.

[image: Current sheet]

The full sheet will have thousands of columns.

I used the code:

Sub CopyC()

```
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim col As Integer

lastrow = Worksheets("macro testing").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 2
lastcol = Worksheets("macro testing").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2

x = 2
col = 2

For i = 3 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, x).Value <> 0 Then
        Cells(lastrow, col).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        col = col + 1
        x = x + 1
    End If
    Next i
```

End Sub

This only works for the first two columns (you'll see the correct dates are spitting out two rows below last row in each column) and then the iteration ends. I THINK it's because the counter is only until last row but I don't know how to fix it so that it keeps going through all columns.

So I need the output to be pulling the date in column A that corresponds with the first non-zero cell in each column.

Additionally, I will also need to run a formula saying if cell <> 0 AND the cell after it DOES = 0 then paste that corresponding date in column A in cells four below lastrow. Not sure if I should nest an ElseIf or just run a different sub?

THANK YOU